# Adding Tool tip using java get content from another div for input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="wpuf-label">
     <label for="post_title">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
</div>

<div class="wpuf-fields">
      <input class="textfield wpuf_post_title_741" id="post_title_741" type="text" data-required="yes" data-type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="" value="" size="40">
</div>
```

This is the code on my form.  I want to add a attribute data-tip to div-wpuf-fields.

Please help me.
Thanking You.

Comment: What is the content that you'll put in that tooltip ?

Comment: Content from label Eg. Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example JavaScript snippet for adding an attribute to the div-wpuf.

```
var wpufFields = document.querySelectorAll(".wpuf-fields");
wpufFields.forEach(function(field) {
  field.setAttribute("data-tip", "value");
});
```

I want to get the value from the label. (Eg. Title)
Sorry. Can any one give the code that i can straightly put it on my website. I don’t know java script very well.

Please!

Thank U!